# How to format JSON string in Javascript returned from controller

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller

I have JSON string returned from controller as shown in below image.

[image: Recieved JSON String]

But I would like that JSON string is formatted in each line as sample show in below image.

[image: Required JSON String]

the following approach i have used so far but unlucky any suggestion / support will be appreciated to achieve the result.

```
$.ajax
                ({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Transaction/showStuContact",
                    data: { "id": id },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        myJSONstring = JSON.stringify(data);

                        myJSONstring1 = myJSONstring.replace(/\\n/g, "")
                            .replace(/ /g, '')
                            .replace(/\\t+/g, "|")
                             .replace(/\\'/g, "")
                             .replace(/\\"/g, '')
                             .replace(/\\&/g, "")
                            .replace(/\\r/g, "")
                            .replace(/\\b/g, "")
                            .replace(/\\f/g, "");

                        alert(myJSONstring1);
                      

                       
                    }
                });
```

Comment: [JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure. The JavaScript function [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) creates a JSON. Doing string replacements on a JSON you risk to break it and render it invalid and unparsable. If you need to change the value you produce then change the properties of `data` or use `data` to produce a different object and encode this new object as JSON and return it.

Comment: Any idea how to turned comma , into line break using replace or any other JS function. I am sure that all I am looking for.

Comment: The formatting of JSON does not matter because its purpose is not to be read by humans but transported or persisted and then parsed to restore data structures similar to the ones used to create it. For transport and persistence, one long line without unnecessary white-space characters is the best. If you need to format it nicely use an editor (most programming editors nowadays know how to format nicely almost anything). If you use the JSON from the command line, [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is perfect for formatting and manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON](https://json.org) is a string representation of some data structure. It does not need to be nicely formatted. Its purpose is not to be read by humans but to be transported or persisted and then parsed to restore from it a data structure similar to the one used to generate it. For this purposes, a long line without unnecessary characters like white spaces or new lines is the best.

However, if you want to produce a JSON that is humanly readable you can invoke [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Syntax) with three arguments. When the third argument is provided, the JSON is formatted on multiple lines and the third argument tells the number of space characters used to indent the lines of the inner blocks (each block relative to its parent block).

```js
const data = {
  id: 123,
  firstname: 'John',
  lastname: 'Doe',
  address: {
    city: 'New York City',
    street: 'any street',
  }
};

// for transport, persistence and restoration
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

// for human consumption
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 3));
```

Run the code snippet above to see the difference.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajax
                ({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Transaction/showStuContact",
                    data: { "id": id },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        myJSONstring = JSON.stringify(data);

                        myJSONstring1 = myJSONstring.replace(/,/g, '\n');
                            //.replace(/ /g, '')
                            //.replace(/\\t+/g, "|")
                            // .replace(/\\'/g, "")
                            // .replace(/\\"/g, '')
                            // .replace(/\\&/g, "")
                            //.replace(/\\r/g, "")
                            //.replace(/\\b/g, "")
                            //.replace(/\\f/g, "");

                            //.replace
                        alert(myJSONstring1);
```

[image]

Comment: The output you produce this way is not JSON anymore. If you don't need JSON then don't encode the data as JSON.

Comment: @axiac it make sense. is there anything else you want to explain or  that's it.